# How to create a button in fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-button

Home fragment code:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    Button interstitial;
    Button BannerAd;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        
    }

}
```

I want to create an button in this fragment for showing ads when I  press that button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are inflating layout `fragment_home` from fragment, you need to add button inside that xml layout file.

**fragment_home.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".HomeFragment">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/my_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Button" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Notice we have added attribute `android:id` with value `my_button` above. Now this helps us to get reference to it in fragment class.

**HomeFragment.java**

```
        // Inside your onViewCreated() add this code to get reference from layout.

        Button myButton = view.findViewById(R.id.my_button);
        myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Add your code
            }
        });
```

Comment: hey brother check my new problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64767123/store-offline-firebase-database-android   @Rajasekhar

Comment: Hey brother please check my new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65024641/download-pdf-and-open-it-in-google-doc-with-download-notification @Rjasekhar