# download pdf and open it in google doc with download notification

Tags: android

I want to make a button that whenever a user presses that button, a PDF will downloaded and that pdf opens in google doc or any other pdf reader.

and that pdf will provide from url.

I am using java programming language. Help me to do this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8383537/download-pdf-from-url-and-read-it?lq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hii Buddy we are having many ways of opening the pdf file in Google Docs

**android intent**

```
   String pdfurl = "http://www.example.com/abcd.pdf";
   String googleDocsUrl = "http://docs.google.com/viewer?url="+pdfurl;
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
   intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(googleDocsUrl ), "text/html");
   startActivity(intent);
```

**web view**

```
WebView webview = new WebView(this); 
setContentView(webview); 
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
webview.loadUrl("example.com/abc.pdf");
```

[learn how to open PDF files](https://blog.mindorks.com/how-to-open-a-pdf-file-in-android-programmatically#:%7E:text=The%20very%20first%20and%20the,loadUrl()%20function.&text=Now%2C%20run%20the%20application%20on,be%20displayed%20on%20the%20screen.)